# Fill arrays with 0 in random place

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array which looks like this

`[ [1], [14, 17], [27], [30, 35], [42, 45], [56, 59], [69], [79], [81, 83, 87]]`

I want to loop over this array and fill out the arrays inside the array with 0 until each of them have 3 values per array. But I don't want to just fill the start or the end I want the 0 to be randomly placed. I am trying to build out a 1-90 bingo card so the numbers are randomly placed in each of the columns.

So the final outcome would look something like

`[ [0, 1, 0], [14, 17, 0], [0, 0, 27], [0, 30, 35], [42, 0, 45], [56, 59, 0], [69, 0, 0], [0, 0, 79], [81, 83, 87]]`

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using `map` method and `while` loop that will insert 0 at random index (max index is 2) of the current element in the map iteration as long as the current element length is < 3.

```js
const data = [ [1], [14, 17], [27], [30, 35], [42, 45], [56, 59], [69], [79], [81, 83, 87]]
const result = data.map(a => {
  let arr = [...a]
  
  while (arr.length < 3) {
    const index = parseInt(Math.random() * 3)
    arr.splice(index, 0, 0)
  }

  return arr
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It does not place the zeros randomly

Comment: @Rainer Plumer What do you mean?

Comment: Looks pretty random to me, just ran the code 3 times and got 3 different results

Comment: Never mind, i guess there weren't enough zeros to be random enough every iteration.
I ran the code 3-4 times and got the same result.

Comment: Why use `map` and assign the result to `result` if you mutate the elements in `data`? Wouldn't it be better to use `forEAch`? You currently give the impression that `data` is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you @NenadVracar for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
const shuffle = (a) => {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}
base = [ [1], [14, 17], [27], [30, 35], [42, 45], [56, 59], [69], [79], [81, 83, 87]];

base.map((subArray) => {
    const itemsToAdd = 3 - subArray.length;
    if (itemsToAdd < 1) {return subArray;}
    const zeros = new Array(itemsToAdd ).fill(0);
    return shuffle(subArray.concat(zeros));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create random number based on lengths of elements available in array and then we can loop over the array and place the values based on condition

```js
let arr = [ [1], [14, 17], [27], [30, 35], [42, 45], [56, 59], [69], [79], [81, 83, 87]]

let randomNumber = _ => {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
}

let final = arr.map(v =>{
  let length = v.length
  let array = new Array(3).fill(undefined)
  let temp = 3 - length
  let set = new Set()
  while(temp){
    let num = randomNumber()
    if(!set.has(num)){
      array[num] = 0
      set.add(num)
    }else {
      continue;
    }
    temp--;
  }
  let index = 0
  return array.map(value=> value !== 0 ? v[index++] : 0)
})

console.log(final)
```